# scrolling using jqueryMobile in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile tutorial they given all scrolling related functionality with examples but if i am using same functionality in phonegap android there scrolling not working please suggest me what shoul i do? I don't want to use iScroll and jQTouch

Thnks
Apurv

Comment: Maybe something wrong in your code. How about your post it (Also links to jQuery scrolling examples please) ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the experimental [jQueryMobile scrollview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/) plugin? ([github link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview))